# mmenu: How to select correct submenu on page load/refresh

Tags: submenu, mmenu

I have a Website with mmenu. There is a submenu. Entering Submenu Displays some entries. I select a submenu and content loads in #content. (jquery/ajax with browser history api).

But if i hit Refresh or enter url manually, i'm starting on main menu and need to re-enter submenu.
I have seen on http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorial/ that there is a way to enter submenus automatically on page load.

How does it work? 
Is there a function that I can call?

Answer (score 0):

the last LI Tag from the submenu must have the following class: 
`.mm-selected`
Now it should be working.